# spring boot not picking test properties when running test classes

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I tried a spring boot 2.4.0 application, wrote some tests. Here's my test class

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
public class SampleTest {
    @Test
    public void testMethod1() {
        //some logic
    }
}
```

I have this structure

```
src/
  main/
    java/
      //// further packages
    resources/
      bootstrap.yml
  test/
    resources/
      application-test.properties
```

Above code is picking bootstrap.yml as it contains this property
spring.profiles.active=${PROFILE}
Btw, this application is using spring-cloud-config

It gives this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'PROFILE' in value "${PROFILE}"
```

Why is spring-boot not picking up my test properties file? It is giving precedence to bootstrap.yml file always. Please help

Comment: Remove TestPropertySource and EnableConfigurationProperties

Comment: Try the same name and extension for test properties. I mean change `application-test.properties` to `application.yml` in `src/test/resource`

Comment: @SimonMartinelli tried EnableConfigurationProperties, didnt work

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your example and it works if I just add this to the test class

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
class SampleTest {
```

You don't need any of the other annotations.

Comment: and you have retained the same structure of test and main properties?

Comment: this still didnt work. I also have spring-kafka-test dependency in my project. could that be interfering in some way?

Comment: Compare your project with mine: https://github.com/simasch/demo-profiles

Comment: I had made a mistake in my post. There's bootstrap.yml instead of application.yml in my project. Now a strange observation, if I change name from bootstrap to application then everything worked fine. Test class picked `src/test/resources/application-test.properties` file!

Comment: Sure because bootstrap.yaml is for Spring Cloud and will be picked up always

Comment: But I had even tried with `@SpringBootTest(properties="spring.cloud.config.enabled=false")`

Comment: This will not help because bootstrap.yaml is even loaded before

Comment: Solved it by doing this
`@SpringBootTest(properties = {"spring.cloud.config.enabled=false", "spring.profiles.active=test"})`
So this basically solved the other property that spring-cloud-config looks for which is that spring.profiles.active and it had a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself with a little help from @SimonMartineli.
My spring-boot 2.4.0 project uses spring-cloud-config. Hence there is bootstrap.yml. It has two properties

```
spring.active.profiles=${PROFILE}
spring.cloud.config.uri=${CONFIG_SERVER_URI}
```

These placeholders are supplied values from env variables in run-time.

Now even if I mention `@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")` in my test classes, it doesnt seem to be working. Test class still tries to load bootstrap.yml fist. It used to work in spring-boot 2.1.5 from which I migrated.

To solve this I used this annotation in my test class.

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = {"spring.cloud.config.enabled=false", "spring.profiles.active=test"}) 
public class SampleTest {
    @Test
    public void testMethod1() {
        //some logic
    }
}
```

So this basically solved the other property that spring-cloud-config looks for which is that spring.profiles.active and it had a placeholder.
Hope this helps someone who faces similar issue.